# Php - convert string to array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array in string like this :

```
"[14,16,18]"
```

I want to remove double quotation and my result would be like :

```
[14,16,18]
```

I've tried :

```
   $restaurantIds =Request::All();
    dd(trim(array_values($restaurantIds)[0], '"'),array_values($restaurantIds)[0] , $restaurantIds)  ;
```

And Result is :

```
"[14,16,18]"
"[14,16,18]"
array:1 [
  "restaurant" => "[14,16,18]"
]
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Strip the square brackets and [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to make it into an array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like below:-

```
<?php

$string = "[14,16,18]";

$array = json_decode($string, true);
print_r($array);
```

Output:- https://eval.in/847737

Another solution:-

```
<?php

$string = "[14,16,18]";

$array = explode(',',str_replace(array('[',']'),array('',''),$string));

print_r($array);
```

Output:-https://eval.in/847734

Comment: If it actually is a json string, you can just do: `$array = json_decode($string, true);`

Comment: @MagnusEriksson  Oh yes.Thanks. Let me add that.